# Trouble With Bootstrap Carousel and a Theme I am building

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a WP theme with Twitter Bootstrap.  I would like to use the carousel but I am having no luck getting the slide to change.  I hope you guys can help me.  I can not seem to find out why this is not working.

This is my `sidebar_carousel.php`

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
    <li class="active" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li class="" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>

<div class="carousel-inner">
    <?php
    $i = 1;
    $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'ss_carousel',
        'posts_per_page' => 3
    ));
    while ($the_query->have_posts()) :
        $the_query->the_post();
        if ($i == 1) {
            ?>
            <div class="item active">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

                    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                    <a class="btn btn-success big" href=""></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
        } else {
            ?>
            <div class="item">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

                    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                    <a class="btn btn-success btn-lg" href=""></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
        }
        $i++; endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</div>
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
</a>

<a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</a>
</div>
```

This is my `functions.php`

```
//Java for carousel
    if (!function_exists('ss_carousel_exists')) :
        function ss_carousel_exists()
        {
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(document).jQuery(function ($) {
                    jQuery('#myCarousel').carousel({
                        interval: 7000
                    })
                });
            </script>
        <?php
        }

        add_action('wp_footer', 'ss_carousel_exists');
    endif;
```

Comment: Hi,I don't know if this the cause of your issue, but WordPress recommand to use wp_enqueue_script() to add javascript to a page. Personnaly I don't know if adding the javascript like you did is a valid method. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I did try wp_enqueue_script() did not work either.  I have added java this way before to my themes and has worked. The only reason I add the code this way is for troubleshooting so I do not have click through pages and get lost. haha which happens to me a lot

Comment: Do you have any console.log error message ?

Comment: I do actually. Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery - Fixed forgot array('jquery')

Comment: That fix the problem with the slides.  Richer thank you saved me a concussion from slamming my head into a wall.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem I was having with the help from Richer.  I had a typo.  If you want to use bootstrap carousel in a WordPress theme the code above works.